# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (node js discord js "discord bot")

Tags: javascript, node.js

Dicord bot and sorry by my english is some bad:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`Genesis bot online!`);
  client.user.setPresence({
    status: "online",
    game: {
      name: "Official Discord Bot",
      type: "PLAYING" //PLAYING, LISTENING, WATCHING
    }
  });
  setInterval(async function(){
    let msg = await client.channels.cache.get(channelID).channel.messages.cache.get(messageID);
    let stafflist = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("GOLD")
    .setTitle("Staff Members")
    .setDescription(client.guilds.cache.get(serverID).roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == "➦「Staff Member」").members.map((m) => `\`${m.user.tag}\``).join(", "));
    msg.edit(stafflist)
  }, 3000);
});
```

this is the complete error:

> (node:276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'get' of undefined
> at Timeout._onTimeout (N:\Genesis bot\Genesisbot2.0\index.js:34:47)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Comment: whatever is on line 34 right before the get method doesn't exist..

Comment: Did you login to the Discord Client with `client.login('INSERT TOKEN HERE')`?

Comment: If the bot logs in correctly all the commands and everything works correctly but that is the only thing that fails, the purpose of that code is to make a message update only by putting all the tags that have a specific roll inside an embed